# error.Clear() on Mailbox role, Transport service installation step

Tags: exchange-server, domaincontroller, exchange-server-2016

I've migrated several Exchange 2013 to 2016 servers, but never did I encounter this error while installing Exchange 2016 on a fresh Windows Server 2016 VM:

Error message: http://misc.schattorie.nl/err.txt

1. IPv6 is enabled and configured correctly
2. I have the correct permissions
3. DNS settings are correct
4. Time settings are correct on the DC and new server
5. I installed the entire server twice, but it keeps giving me this exact error...

I'm kind of lost now :S

**Edit:** The server has also received al the Windows UPdates, I started installing Exchange 2016 CU8 first, but when it failed with this error, I tried CU11, which resulted in the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently when in step 6 at 97% the setup hangs, and than fails with the above error. For some reason I need to manually enable the Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology service, but you need to do it at this exact moment... For some reason the setup stops the service right before it's going to use it...

Comment: I've noticed more and more that starting Exchange services seem to get trickier and trickier. Watching my event logs, it appears to be an issue with loading performance monitors when trying to start the service, just an FYI.